# Python | Selenium | Procurando elemento html

Tags: html, python, selenium-webdriver

Olá pessoal sou iniciante em python e pouco conhecimento em html, estou tentando fazer faz uma busca de informações em um dvr Intelbras via pagina web.

- até um certo ponto eu conseguir fazer o que era de esperado, porém não estou seguir em frente na busca de um elemento. segue o caminho do elemento _storage:

[image: Esse é o caminho completo do elemento _storage que eu quero buscar]

Conseguir seguir do Html até o frame_set(Marcado em verde), depois disso não conseguir seguir para o próximo html
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei varias formas e não encontro nada na na internet e nem em documentação

segue codigo python:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import IEDriverManager
from time import sleep


driver = webdriver.Ie(IEDriverManager().install())
driver.get('http://192.168.15.2/')
if driver.find_element_by_class_name('login-inputbox').is_displayed():
driver.find_element_by_id('username').send_keys("py")
driver.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys("py")
driver.find_element_by_class_name('login_confirm').click()
sleep(15)
driver.find_element_by_id('xxtpz').click()
sleep(3)
element_one = driver.find_element_by_id('m')
sleep(3)
element_two = element_one.find_element_by_id('f_setup')
sleep(3)
element_tree = element_one.find_element_by_id('frame_set')
```

Alguem poderia me dá um help por favor?

Comment: Precisa ser feito com selenium? Eu pergunto pois acredito que o selenium seja uma ferramenta exagerada para uma simples raspagem de dados.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que me parece, você está tentando buscar por um elemento que não está localizado dentro do frame principal da página. Por padrão o frame principal ou aquele que está disponível quando você abre uma página é denominado **default_content**. Se algum elemento estiver dentro de um outro frame você não irá localizá-lo sem "entrar" neste frame. Se você estiver dentro de um frame e o elemento estiver no default_content você não conseguirá localizá-lo sem voltar para o frame principal. Tente mudar para este frame antes, com

```
>> driver.switch_to_frame(frame)
```

Após feito isso, busque pelo elemento que deseja novamente!